# wordpress contact form 7 to sync to mailchimp list using api

Tags: php, wordpress, api, mailchimp, contact-form-7

I am trying to send contact form 7 data to mailchimp list.  So far this works well following this tutorial http://www.limecanvas.com/a-mailchimp-opt-in-field-for-contact-form-7/

I am trying to modify the php to collect a telephone number and post that as a merge tag into the mailchimp list.

```
function wpcf7_send_to_mailchimp($cfdata) {
     $formtitle = $cfdata->title;
     $formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
     // Opt-in field checked?
     if ( $formdata['mailchimp-optin'] ) {
     $names = explode(' ',trim($formdata['first-name']));
     $firstName = $names[0];
     $lastName = '';
     if (count($names)>1){
     // more than one word in name field
     $lastName = array_pop($names);
     }
    $send_this_email = $formdata['your-email'];
     $mergeVars = array(
     'FNAME'=>$firstName,
     'LNAME'=>$lastName
     );
     // MCAPI.class.php needs to be in theme/includes folder
    require_once('core/includes/MCAPI.class.php');

     // grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
     $api = new MCAPI('apikey');
     // grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
     // Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page.
     $list_id = 'listid';
     // Send the form content to MailChimp List without double opt-in
     $retval = $api->listSubscribe($list_id, $send_this_email, $mergeVars, 'html', false,true);
     }
    }
    add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_send_to_mailchimp', 1);
```

I have setup the form field in mailchimp and am trying this:

```
$telephone = $formdata['you-tell'];
```

and adding the merge tag to the mergetag array:

```
'TELL'=>$telephone
```

I am not a php guy (more comfortable with jquery) so I might be approaching this wrong?

essentially I need to extract the data from contact form 7 and add to the mailchimp mergetag array.

Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 1):

[MailChimp for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) does just that. It uses the MailChimp API in combination with the WordPress HTTP API which makes it less error prone.

The following Contact Form 7 template will feed the entered values to your MailChimp list.

```
[text* mc4wp-FNAME]

[text* mc4wp-LNAME]

[tel mc4wp-TELL]

[mc4wp_checkbox "Sign-up to our newsletter."]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

ok, Figured it out... really simple:

```
 $tell = $formdata['your-tell'];
 $mergeVars = array(
 'FNAME'=>$firstName,
 'LNAME'=>$lastName,
 'TELL'=>$tell
 );
```

Ammended these lines